# Preserve permissions and ownership with install command

Tags: permissions, coreutils

When running `install` (GNU Coreutils implementation), I'd like to know if it is possible to preserve ownership and permissions of the source files. I know that by default it installs as `755`, and you can change this with `-m`, however is it possible to preserve the permissions and ownership to be the same as that of the source files?

I am aware that `cp` has functionality to preserve ownership and permissions, however under my circumstances, I need to use `install`, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no option to do it. You could fake it for example by using `stat` to record the owner, group and mode information and using that. Something like

```
#!/bin/sh
install $(stat -c '-m %a -g %g -o %u' "$1") "$1" "$2"
```

(Do not use this script in production, it is seriously lacking in checking, it just accepts 2 arguments, the SRC and DEST rather than all the options that `install` does).